# How to convert SRID's on the fly and via command line, on INSERTION's query in PostGIS?

Tags: postgis, geoserver, postgresql, sql

We are working on a project that used shapefiles in order to build our first PostGIS database, through a tool called “PostGIS Shapefile Import/Export Manager”.

[image: Tool Screeen]

The problem is that now we need to create new tables onto that same PostGIS DB, through executing SQL commands line, as detailing bellow.

**0 – VERSIONS:**
a – PostGIS: 2.0.7 r13406
b – Geoserver: 2.12.1

**1 – CREATING TABLE QUERY:**

```
CREATE TABLE tabela (gid serial, nome varchar, geom geometry(Point, 32724));
```

**2 – INSERTING A POINT QUERY:**

```
INSERT INTO tabela (nome, geom)
VALUES('Teste Renan', ST_GeomFromText('POINT(-40.388527 -20.339450)', 32724));
```

By inserting that point via command line, Geoserver cannot correctly calculate “Lat/Long Bounding Box”, when I press the “Compute from native bounds” button, at the “New Layer” screen. 
It give strange values, denoting some problem.

P.S.: I have properly set up EPSG 32724 (WGS84 24S).

[image: Usual and weird values.]

By doing this process, when I try to **preview** that specific layer, **nothing appear**.

Another strange thing that I have noticed is different values for GEOM field, for the “almost” same place: 
**a - When created by “PostGIS Shapefile Import/Export Manager”:**

```
0101000000DCD8FFFF83BD1541B1FE00804F915D41
```

or using `st_asewkt` command:

```
POINT(356192.999999417 7750974.00006072)
```

**b – When created by command line:**

```
0101000020D47F0000774EB340BB3144C090A0F831E65634C0
```

or using `st_asewkt` command:

```
SRID=32724;POINT(-40.388527 -20.33945)
```

Any thoughts on how to solve this problem or how to properly create the query for add point to **TABELA** table?

Comment: Please [edit] your question title to focus on one question, as per the [Tour]

Comment: Bounding box of a single point is just a point. That is correct but may give troubles for GeoServer. Increase the bounds to a real box manually. Also, your point seems to be in EPSG:4326.

Comment: Sorry @Vince, hope the title is OK now. Thanks for the comment, @user30184!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to project those points to your CRS; when using `ST_GeomFromText(<point>, <srid>)`, the given coordinates are treated as units in respect to the given SRID (so, in your case, that sets your point roughly at the equator and next to the UTM zone's reference meridian, as the values are treated as *meter*).
Try

```
INSERT INTO tabela (nome, geom)
VALUES('Teste Renan', ST_Transform(ST_GeomFromText('POINT(-40.388527 -20.339450)', 4326), 32724));
```

Note: this assumes your initial geographic coordinates are based on EPSG:4326.

Comment: I may am commiting a mistake, due to forum's policy, but I want to THANK YOU, @ThingumaBob! Your query worked out PERFECTLY on our project's environment.

Comment: @RenanMenelli well, you're welcome! ...apart from GeoServers quirks, e.g. the comment by user30184, I cannot stress out enough how essential it is to know your projections and how PostGIS works with them. this is a massive topic, but fundamental. you will be *terrorized* by errors and missing geometries and whatnot in your workflow if you make mistakes here...get a good read, is what I'm trying to say ,)